# Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

Desenvolvi uma página em PHP para uso interno da empresa que trabalho e apenas pouquíssimas pessoas a utilizam. Através dessa página é possível fazer algumas consultas, inserções, alterações e remoções de dados de uma tabela em um banco de dados MySQL, porém eu acredito que meu código em PHP não está protegido contra injeção de código SQL, por exemplo:

```php
//----CONSULTA SQL----//
$busca = mysql_query ('insert into Produtos (coluna) values(' . $valor . ')');
```

Logo, digamos que o usuário usar a sentença: `1); DROP TABLE Produtos;` para ao campo `valor` o comando ficaria:

```sql
insert into Produtos (coluna) values(1); DROP TABLE Produtos;
```

Ele vai inserir um novo registro cujo o campo `coluna` será `1` e logo em seguida ele vai deletar a tabela `Produtos`.

Como posso melhorar meu código para prevenir essa situação?

Comment: Existe muitas formas de prevenir o SQL injection. Recomendo a seguinte leitura: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: A query montada acredito que seria

 $busca = mysql_query ('insert into Produtos (coluna) values('1); DROP TABLE Produtos;')');, talvez não fosse aceita no banco, porém sempre faça o tratamento dos dados recebidos pelo usuário antes de interagir com o banco...removendo caracteres especiais.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

1 - **NÃO** utilize as funções mysql_* pois as mesmas são consideradas obsoletas (deprecated) e logo serão removidas. [Mais alguns motivos para não usá-las.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/porque-nao-devemos-usar-funcoes-do-tipo-mysql)

Utilize *prepared statements*, isso vai reduzir a vulnerabilidade de *sql injection*, pois a consulta é dividida em duas partes, o comando sql e as marcações(`?` ou `:nome`)  que serão substituidos pelos valores, o primeiro é executado já o segundo mesmo contendo uma instrução sql válida será tratado como texto puro.

As marcações não podem substituídas por nomes de *databases*, tabelas/*views*, colunas e valores nas clásulas `ORDER BY` ou `GROUP BY`.

Existem dois drivers que suportam isso, o [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) e o [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Exemplo de *prepared staments* com PDO:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost dbname=teste', 'usuario', 'senha');

$sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela(campo1, campo2, campo3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue(1, 'valor1');
$stmt->bindValue(2, 'valor2');
$stmt->bindValue(3, 'valor3');

$stmt->execute(); // executa o insert ou outra sql
```

Exemplo de *prepared staments* com mysqli:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'teste');

$sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela(campo1, campo2, campo3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
if(!$stmt){
    echo 'erro na consulta: '. $db->errno .' - '. $db->error;
}

$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 'foo';
$var3 = 1.99;
$stmt->bind_param('isd', $var1, $var2, $var3);
$stmt->execute();
```

A string `isd` corresponde aos tipos de dados passados que são integer, string, double e `b` para campos blob conforme o [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: Para completar utilize as funções que limpam os dados recebidos por POST ou GET. Procure sempre validar suas variáveis antes de passá-las para um SQL. Utilize as funcões filter_input e filter_var para lhe auxiliar. Veja a documentação. http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php

Comment: @Math A extensão `mysql_*` foi depreciada e mostra um E_DEPRECATED quando conectando a base de dados a partir do PHP 5.5 (mas claro que é melhor adotar prepared statements independente da versão que você usa)

Comment: PDO não é o mais recomendado para consultas preparadas, a preparação de consultas é emulada no lado do cliente e por isso é mais lenta.

Answer (score 53):

Existem várias formas de se prevenir SQLInjection. Dois exemplos são:

- [Função mysql_real_escape_string do php](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) Uma forma genérica
- [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) A forma realmente eficiente

Recomendo que dê uma lida na segunda opção e adote o [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) para manipulação de sua base de dados.

Leia também: [mysql_real_escape_string() versus Prepared Statements](http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html)

Comment: `Prepared Statements` parece a forma mais correta mesmo, pois ele não permite os caracteres da injeção. A outra opção ainda é válida ou ela também está depreciada?

Comment: O mysql_real_escape_string já é setado como deprecated no PHP 5.5.0 e será removida em futuras versões. A PDO é sim a mais correta.

Comment: Eu assisti uma video-aula que o cara usava "mysqli_real_escape_string". Não existe?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` faz parte do pacote do `mysql_*` no PHP. Essas funções já estão disparando mensagem de `E_DEPRECATED`. Daqui a pouco se tornarão obsoletas e - espero - todos deverão migrar para o PDO ou `mysqli`.

Comment: @IWannaKnow existe e é eficaz.

Comment: Usar essas funções "escape" é uma solução temporária antes de substituir a API mysql_ por mysqli_. É muito fácil esquecer de escapear algum lugar. Sugiro editar a resposta indicando que é uma solução stopgap e não recomendada.

Comment: O usuário @IWannaKnow falou mysqli, e mysqli ainda é válido!!!

Answer (score 40):

Não é mais recomendado a utilização da biblioteca mysql será descontinuada nas próximas versões.

Para tanto existe algumas soluções:

https://www.php.net/mysqli

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php

http://medoo.in/ esta é a que eu uso. Já tem muitas sql genérica pronta! Vale a pena conferir.

OBS: a biblioteca mais rápida é a mysqli, pois por baixo as duas usam mysqli.

Answer (score 36):

Simplesmente não use string concatenation, use parametros SQL sempre, ou uma lib que o faça por si.

No seu exemplo com parametro o user inseriria '1); DROP TABLE Produtos;' na coluna, se esta o permitisse, caso contrário receberia um estoiro.

Na minha framework eu estou a usar o NotORM para a camada de dados, e previne muitos problemas inerentes ao SQL injection, e usa também a interface PDO ;) http://pedrosimoes79.github.io/silverbullet/

No caso do NotORM usam o PDO::quote

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/notorm/3kR2o9iI5xQ

usando este código no Model:

```
function getHelloworldMySQL()
{
    $this->db->hello2->test->insert([
        'text' => "'Hello with a drop'); DROP TABLE Produtos;"
    ]);

    foreach ($this->db->hello2->test as $id => $hello) {
        return $hello['text'];
    }
}
```

obtemos ;)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 30):

Achei estranho ninguém citar

**Stored Procedure.**

Além de evitar SQL Injection, você ganha perfomance, visto que elas são compiladas.

```
Create PROCEDURE stp_ExemploInsert
@nome varchar(200),
@idade smallint

as

BEGIN
Set nocount on; --não traz nenhum retorno de linha extra;

Insert tabela_exemplo (nome,idade) values (@nome, @idade)

END
```

Dai no PHP, não me recordo bem mas era

```
$stmt = mssql_init('Nome_Procedure');
mssql_bind($stmt, '@nome','Felipe Pena',SQLVARCHAR,false,false,0);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@idade ',25,SQLINT2);
mssql_execute($stmt);
mssql_free_statement($stmt);
```

**Update 2023**

```
Você pode chamar a stored procedure no php assim:
// Definir os parâmetros
$nome = "ExemploNome";
$idade = 25;

// Montar a chamada da stored procedure
$sql = "{call stp_ExemploInsert (?, ?)}";

// Preparar a execução da stored procedure
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, array(&$nome, &$idade));
sqlsrv_execute($stmt)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-execute.php

OBS: Stored Procedure é invulnerável, desde que você não faça algo assim!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getDescription
   @vname VARCHAR(50)
AS
   EXEC('SELECT description FROM products WHERE name = '''+@vname+ '''')
RETURN
```

Que alias isso é um horror!
Cursores também pode ser perigosos a SQL injector, porém é bem mais complexo.

Comment: Seu exemplo continua vulnerável a SQL Injection, pois não existe nenhum tratamento ao passar os parâmetros nome e idade.

Comment: na stored procedure vc enviando os valores como parametros não existe problema de injeção, não sei como em PHP chamar a storedprocedure para enviar como parametro... mas fazendo isso é 100% seguro..

Answer (score 22):

Uma boa forma de previnir injeções de SQL é também já utilizando soluções prontas para este.

Talvez, a utilização de `Frameworks Full Stacks` - que já possuem várias soluções prontas para o programador, desde validações até segurança - possa ajudar em relação à segurança de sua aplicação.

Caso não haja necessidade da utilização de um `Framework Full Stack`, eu optaria pela utilização de um framework para abstração de banco de dados (ORMs), como o `Doctrine 2`.

Digo isso porque os Frameworks geralmente são projetados também com esse tipo de preocupação: A segurança.

Answer (score 12):

Além de parar de utilizar as bibliotecas depreciadas como já foi dito como resposta, você deve checar os seus queries para poder verificar se algum deles está passando algo sensível sem criptografia, se algum formulário seu está passando métodos em **GET** e etc.

**Existem várias técnicas para você poder se prevenir só depende de você encontrar qual seria a melhor no seu caso e a utilizar.**

Comment: Além disto, não deixe nenhuma query com busca muito aberta podendo retornar dados de outra linha ou coluna de seu DB

Answer (score 10):

Pode-se usar junto com as `prepared statements` a função `filter_var()`. Mas calma, `filter_var` tem várias utilidades, por exemplo:

```
filter_var('marcelo@g.c', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);//retorna boolean true
filter_var('marcelo@g.c\\', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);//retorna string "marcelo@g.c"
```

Vocé pode estar dando uma olhada na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php) para uma abordagem sobre SQL injection, que voce não vai achar de cara, apenas de uma olhada nas constantes que podem ser usadas.

Answer (score 5):

Eu uso o **framework Doctrine ORM** para a camada de dados. Frameworks evitam SQL injection.

Para uma visão geral do Doctrine: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html cobrindo instalação com o *composer* e exemplo básico de Mapeamento Objeto-Relacional.

Sobre sua pergunta, utilizando a inserção de um produto, essa documentação tem um exemplo para o mesmo caso. É simples e você fica protegido.

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Annotation as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity @ORM\Table(name="products")
**/
class Product
{
/** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue **/
protected $id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
protected $name;

// .. (other code)
}
```

A inserção:

```
<?php
// create_product.php <name>
require_once "bootstrap.php";

$newProductName = $argv[1];

$product = new Product();
$product->setName($newProductName);

$entityManager->persist($product);
$entityManager->flush();
```